# listview widget rebuild each time the textfiled is focused

Tags: flutter, dart

Each time the textfield widget is focused, the listview.builder widget totally rebuild. I've tried many things including adding the textfield and the listview.buider  widgets to their own classes, but none of that worked. What can I do to fix the problem? Here is my code:
I tried add the listview.builder and the texfield widgets in separate classes. I also tried to wrap the textfield widget in a showmodalbottomsheet before trying the previously mentioned.

```
Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('comments')
                .where('postId', isEqualTo: document['postId'])
                //.orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
                .limit(
                    _numComments) //limit comments to prevent unnecssary reads.
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                    snapshot) {
              //reply count

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }

              int numComments = snapshot.data!.docs.length;
              return StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                  return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                    onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
                      if (scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent ==
                          scrollInfo.metrics.pixels) {
                        setState(() {
                          _numComments += _increment;
                        });
                      }
                      return true;
                    },
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: numComments,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => CommentCard(
                        snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index],
                        document: document,
                        user: userInfo?.username as String,
                        focus: focusNode,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),

        //SizedBox(height: height*0.1,),
        const Divider(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.face,
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {}),
              Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                onChanged: (value) {},
                //controller: commentEditingController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Say something on this...",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    border: InputBorder.none),
              )),
              IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(postIcons.send_1,
                      color: Colors.blueAccent),
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var commentId = const Uuid().v1(); //docid

                    openingPage.reply &&
                            commentEditingController.text.isNotEmpty
                        ? db
                            .collection('replies')
                            .doc(document['postId'])
                            .set({
                            'author': userInfo?.username,
                            'comment': commentEditingController.text.trim()
                          })
                        : FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('comments')
                            .doc(commentId)
                            .set({
                            'postId': document['postId'],
                            'commentId': commentId,
                            "comment": commentEditingController.text.trim(),
                            "datePublished": Timestamp.now(),
                            "profilePhoto": userInfo?.photoUrl == null
                                ? ""
                                : userInfo?.photoUrl as String,
                            "username": userInfo?.username,
                          });
                    commentEditingController.clear();
                  })
            ],
          );
        }),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Are they sharing the same focusNodes? That's the TextField and the CommentCards

Comment: They're sharing the same focusNode.

Comment: Try granting them different focusNodes. Why do you need to set focusNodes for the CommentCards ?

Comment: The focusNode isn't he problem. Before i included it, I was still getting the same rebuilding result.